# ¿La frase "donde mismo", es correcta?

Tags: méxico

Hace unos días, platicando con unos compañeros, se llegó a la discusión de si la frase "`donde mismo`" es correcta o no.

El contexto es el siguiente:

Se encuentran dos amigos después de no verse durante un año. Al platicar el primer amigo le pregunta al segundo:

> - ¿Y donde vives ahora?

A lo que el segundo amigo responde:

> - Donde mismo.

Haciendo referencia a su hogar que es conocido previamente por el primer amigo.

Entonces, ¿es correcta la frase "`donde mismo`" ?

Comment: con correcto te refieres a si es valida por la RAE?

Comment: @luisluix Sí, exacto.

Comment: Sucede parecido con la expresión "Donde único yo estoy bien es allí", que se usa también en algunas regiones de América.

Answer (score 7):

Era la primera vez que veía esa expresión, <del>definitivamente</del> diría que en el español peninsular no existe: solemos decir «donde siempre», entre otras.

Sin embargo una búsqueda en internet lo revela bastante popular (185.000 resultados).

Ese uso se recoge por escrito como mínimo desde 1969:

```
Puede parecer un disparate gramatical decir: vivo donde mismo. 
Pero es que el uso da vida a muchas locuciones que toman carta 
de ciudadanía y las impone. En vez de decir: vivo allí mismo 
donde ya me viste uno dice, con mayor brevedad y llaneza: 
vivo donde mismo. Y todos entienden.
```

—Muñoz, Diego. *[Lenguaje vivo: consultorio del idioma](https://books.google.ch/books?id=EuhLTTPs5B8C)*.

Aunque [el autor de *Lenguaje vivo*](http://www.tajamar-editores.cl/autor/199) reconozca su uso, no he podido encontrar instituciones que lo avalen.

Comment: Añado: la primera edición de _Lenguaje vivo_ aparentemente es de finales de los **años treinta** según la reseña de Tajamar Editores.

Answer (score 4):

Hay otros casos en los que **mismo** también se usa después de adverbio o frase adverbial, al menos en mi experiencia en Chile:

> **Ahora mismo** te lo devuelvo.
>
> Está **ahí mismo**, junto a la radio.
>
> Lo pusieron **al lado mismo** de mi casa.
>
> El cráter está **debajo mismo** del parque.
>
> Te espero **acá mismo**.
>
> Hazlo **así mismo**. (*hazlo del mismo modo*)

Entonces no veo el problema en usarlo después del adverbio relativo **donde** (o **cuando** o **como**). El asunto es que después de un relativo debería venir una oración subordinada, pero me imagino que el significado de "mismo" (*idéntico*) nos permite hacer una elipsis.

> Juntémonos en el lugar en que ya nos juntamos.
>
> Juntémonos donde ya nos juntamos.
>
> Juntémonos donde mismo.